# Why does the scikit median filter produce a blank output image?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I am trying to de-noise the following picture using the `median` filter of `Scikit Image`.

[image]

This is a picture with a dimension of 250 X 100 pixels. The pixels are either black or white.

```
dtype=uint8
shape=(100,250)
max=255
min=0
```

This is the Python script

```
import os
from skimage import io
from skimage.filters.rank import median
from skimage.morphology import disk


def median_filter(inputfilename):
    folder_script=os.path.dirname(__file__)
    absolute_filename=os.path.join(folder_script,"./in/",inputfilename)

    original= io.imread(absolute_filename, as_gray=True)
    
    median_filtered=median(original, disk(50))  #5, 10, 20,100

    filename_result="median-filter-output.png"
    file_result=os.path.join(folder_script,"./out/",filename_result)
    io.imsave(file_result,median_filtered)

median_filter(inputfilename="NoisySine.png")
```

The resulting image is always blank (full white).  I am sure I am doing something wrong - but not clear where.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Sau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your image is almost full white the median of such large disk is also white.

As extreme example, Imagine a disk that has 51% whites pixels and 49% black pixels -> the median will be white. In your case is looks like at least 95%
white dominance.

BTW, it is `as_grey` and not `as_gray` (update: was like this but not anymore, see @Juan comment below)

Comment: I am referring to https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread
Are you sure that it should be `as_grey` and not `as_gray` ? Thank you.

Comment: It *used to be* `as_grey`, but now is indeed `as_gray`. We decided to use American spelling throughout the library, whereas historically it was left to individual contributors' tastes.

Other than that, the answer is correct: a median filter will only give you a black pixel if > 50% of the surrounding pixels are black. You can see that that will never happen in the above image. In your case, I think you will need to model your data points (e.g. as a sinusoid) in order to determine noise vs signal. See this example: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_ransac.html

Comment: @sau001, the gray was just a side note and thanks to Juan I see the confusion.
Anyhow, median should working even if it was RGB.
Did you understand my answer regarding why u got white image?

Comment: @Juan - You got me!  I am indeed on the road to using RANSAC. I am exploring an approach which helps in determining any smooth curve in a noisy image(not just sine) by running RANSAC on a patch  by patch basis. The assumption here is that any smooth curve is made up linear segments. It is my belief that when the human eye sees a large picture, the mind analyzes the picture by breaking into small regions and extracting basic features like lines, curves, etc.